# Facebook video advertising in Unity on mobiles

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, ads, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to integrate rewarded video ads into my Unity game, targeting mobile devices (not web/canvas). Does Facebook provide video ads via its [Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity)? Found no explicit mentioning of video neither in reference, nor in plugin package.

Comment: hey @Qbit did you find out if it is possible?
More specifically i want to know if i can introduce native video adverts into unity? is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

As I know it does not provide video ads.
I found the best way to integrate advertisements to a Unity project is UnityAds. It is pretty simple and clean.